# Should I store an attribute with only 2 possible values has a Boolean, Number, or String in MongoDB?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

So I have an attribute for a table that can either take on the values of `yes` or `no`.

What are some reasons I should store it as a Boolean: `yes` -> true, `no` -> false.
What are some reasons I should store it as a Number : `yes` -> 1, `no` -> 0.
What are some reasons I should store it as a String : `yes` -> "yes", `no` -> "no"

Is storing it as a String the most expensive in terms of space?

Comment: I'd chose string. Or boolean. Never number.

Comment: Any reasons against numbers?

Comment: A non-programmer doesn't understand 1 means yes. Data should be understandable for everyone, not just C programmers.

Comment: I'd choose Boolean. I think it's clear enough that it's representing a yes/no dichotomy. I also imagine Booleans cost less to evaluate than string comparison.